# C#: Checking an array for a sub-array

Tags: arrays, combinations

I would like to know an efficient way in C# to check if a sub-array exists within a larger array, the arrays will always be in numerical order, for example:

```
x = {1,2,3,4,5,6}
y = {3,4}
z = {6,7}
```

y in x = TRUE

z in x = FALSE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var x = new HashSet<int>(Enumerable.Range(1,6)); // [1,2,3,4,5,6]
var y = Enumerable.Range(1,3); // [1,2,3]
var z = Enumerable.Range(6,2); // [6,7]
x.IsSupersetOf(y); // true
x.IsSupersetOf(z); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider your y in x example.
First of all You can check

```
if(y[0] <= x[x.length-1])
    //binary search in array x for y[y.length-1]
    //if that is true u can say that y in x else false.
```

Comment: Nice approach.  A very simple extension to this is to binary search for both ends of the sub array.